# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session error launching the iOS app in Kobiton cloud

Tags: java, ios, selenium, mobile, automation

While trying to execute the automation script for ios platform in kobiton I am getting the below error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities {app: kobiton-store:v355928, autoGrantPermissions: true, captureScreenshots: true, deviceGroup: KOBITON, deviceName: iPhone X, deviceOrientation: portrait, groupId: 2979, platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 14.8, sessionDescription: iOS Automated Scripts Execu..., sessionName: Test Automa...}
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'C-L-233', ip: '192.168.0.110', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.lambda$1(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:192)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:192)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:95)
```

I have also followed the proper syntax for the kobiton launching apps. Also find the desired capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability("sessionName", "Test Automation - MS")
capabilities.setCapability("sessionDescription", "iOS Automated Scripts Execution")
capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait")
capabilities.setCapability("captureScreenshots", true)
capabilities.setCapability("app", "kobiton-store:v355928")
capabilities.setCapability("groupId", XXXX)
capabilities.setCapability("deviceGroup", "KOBITON")
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", iPhone X)
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", 14.8)
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS")
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true")
```

Any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The *JDK* version is old and ancient:

```
java.version: '1.8.0_291'
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).

Comment: Is it good to upgrade the JDK as I am executing the tests on kobiton cloud and not on physical device ?

Comment: I am not sure about your specific case, but whats the harm in upgrading _JDK_?

Comment: Ok will upgrade.

Comment: Even after upgrade facing the same issue.